# pdo fetchAll() returns empty array()

Tags: php, arrays, pdo, fetchall

I have been trying for over a day now to get FetchAll() method to help me display array from database. But all my efforts have failed. Instead of the print_r() returning an array, it gives me this array(). Kindly, help me out.
The code in class page :

```
class Article {
public function fetch_all(){
    global $conn;
    $ass = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
    $ass->execute();
     return $ass->fetchAll();


    }

}
```

while the code in display page is:

```
$article = new Article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all();
 print_r($articles);
```

Comment: Check your error logs or try/catch from PDO. Are you sure that PDO correctly connect to the Database? Check `$conn` with `var_dump();`!

Comment: Nice variable naming!

Comment: I am sure my PDO connected correctly to the Database.  I used try catch, and it doesn't throw any exception.  The var_dump(); didn't show anything.

Answer (score 4):

`$query` is not defined in your code, `$ass->fetchAll();` is what you should have.

Comment: the problem persists when I use $ass->fetchAll(); This has been frustrating. Can you think up another reason why the array will be empty?

Answer (score 0):

`$query` is not defined. Consider injecting your database object into the Article object to avoid using globals.

```
class Article {
   public function fetch_all(PDO $conn){
    $ass = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
    $ass->execute();
        return $ass->fetchAll();  
    }

} 

$article = new Article;
$articles = $article->fetch_all($conn);
print_r($articles);
```

Injecting your PDO object can make changing the code easier down the line.

Comment: I have changed $query to $ass, but the array() is still empty. I keep the database object separate because I want the coding to be tidy. Can the use of global cause the problem of empty array()?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried the following code below it works perfect.

```
class Article {
        public function fetch_all(){
            global $connection;
            $ass = $connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM test");
            $ass->execute();
            return $ass->fetchAll();
        }
    } 


    $article = new Article;
    $articles = $article->fetch_all();
    print_r($articles);
```

As you see above i have used my $connection and it works perfect.
So, the problem is definitely on your $conn (connection).
check your connection again.

Comment: Test, I shall try cheking my connection

Answer (score 0):

It has eventually started returning full array. All I did was to uninstal the WAMPserver I was using and replace it with another one.